# Why is my storyline progress undone by playing multiplayer?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I got Diablo 3 on my PlayStation 4 and I am very new to the game as I do not know much about it.  I played the regular solo campaign and then I went to quick match and tried to play with some people.
I realized we were doing a quest I've already done in campaign. So I quit and went back to solo campaign and it set me back quite some ways and now I have to re-do a bunch of quests?

Comment: For what it's worth, most online matches are going to be with people who may not be on the same quests as you. If they're further back than you were, there's no reason not to join them, as you'll still be earning loot and XP.

Comment: i understand that, but after i was done playing with the person i went back into my regular campaign like solo you know? and it said my main quest was something i've already done and it seems to have set me back in progress.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am only familiar with the PC version. While I believe there is a way to set your current quest to the beginning of the furthest mission along the main quest-line you've reached; I do not know where this option may be on the console version of the game.

Comment: I'll look later on. Though try starting a new game, it should give you an option for quest selection. Or join another multiplayer. Pretty sure quest selection is an optuon, you will not lose your character progression.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to choose what Act and Mission to play from the main menu. If you haven't finished the game on higher difficulty levels, or haven't finished the game on the first difficulty level yet, then the missions/acts you haven't done yet will be grayed out.

Since the game treats online and offline the same, it will have put you back to where the group you joined was. If you press continue from the main menu, you'll end up doing missions you've already done.

Instead, choose the latest mission from the mission select/difficulty select screen.

You may have lost your current progress in that mission, but all your gear and gold will still be there.

I hope this makes sense :)

P.S. The game is made so you can go back and play in previous areas. You get to keep loot and gold, then you can carry on back to where you left off. Everything is tied to your character, not to the story line. So as long as you don't create a new character or delete your current one, it won't matter what missions you play. But to get better gear, you need to finish the game on it's hardest difficulty. Which is unlocked by beating the previous difficulty and so on. Which requires you to go through the story line.